# Importing csv into sql database with different columns

Tags: sql, database, laravel, csv, import

I have a Laravel-mix project. My client wants to import 20,000 fields into the database. For example,

Table 1: Assets has rows such as category_id, room_id.
Table 2: Categories have an id which is used as a foreign key to connect to the Asset table and the same for a room.

The CSV that the client is providing me has a category name and not the id. The asset table has a row for category_id only.  How can I import the data with the category name and connect it to categories id.

Note: This is one time thing and I am using TablePlus/PhpMyAdmin to import the data through CSV file.

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: @jarlh yeah. Any information could be helpful.

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL related questions.